# Making a profile and storing it in a map for each user

Tags: java

Hello I was wondering if anyone could help me with my little problem, When i add a user using AddUser(Username1) it adds the user, but the next user i add with a diffrent username (username2) overrides the current profile causing there to be 2 profiles with the username of username2.
so instead of returning username1 and username2 it returns, username2 and username2.

(both of these classes are simplified, the user class would ofc hold other info like id, balance ect..)

My User class:

```
public class TakaneUser {
String Username;

public TakaneUser(String user1){
this.Username = user1
}
public static String getUserName() {
    return Username;
}
```

My Userhandler / adding users to map class:

```
static Map<String, TakaneUser> Usermap = new HashMap();
public static void adduser(String user){
    Usermap.put(user, new TakaneUser(user));
}
```

Update: Problem is solved, im stupid,

Comment: The code looks fine. Try making the Username field private and final to limit visibility and stopping changes to it.

Comment: It's probably the keyword `static` from the `getUserName()` method, however I don't even know why this compile (what does `this` mean in a static method? If it's the class, then what is this `Username` field? It shouldn't be able to access instance data)

Comment: It can't compile with `this` in a static method...

Comment: _this_ - Cannot use in _static_ context !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code does not compile but this one should do the job

```
public class TakaneUser {
    private String username;

    public TakaneUser(String user) {
         this.username = user;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
         return username;
    }
```

and then

```
static Map<String, TakeaneUser> userMap = new HashMap<>();
public static void addUser(String user){
    userMap.put(user, new TakaneUser(user));
}
```

Explanations : If your username is static, it means it is not related to an instance but related to the class, hence every TakaneUser instances will share the same username.